# Key, value and index

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary

My problem is quite simple. I have some data associated to a Key. The key and data are both `NSString`. So the first thing which comes to my mind is to use `NSDictionary`. 
I usually access to the value like this: `[myDict objectForKey:@"myKey"];`
However, sometimes I need to access to the value by index.

sample:    `[myDict objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]`

But of course, there is no index in a Dictionary.

There are many solutions to solve this problem, but I would like to know which one is the best.

**What is the best way to access to a value thanks to its key or its index ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your custom class say `DictionArray` having properties of arrays and dictionaries.

Add properties `NSInteger index`, `NSString *value` etc and some methods to retrieve based on index and keys.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an object from a dictionary by index you have to have an array of keys. Then you get the key:

```
NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

and get the object:

```
NSString *value = [myDict objectForKey:key];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no much sense in this, since dictionaries are unordered, but if you need this anyway:

```
id nthKey = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:idx];
id nthObj = [dict objectForKey:nthKey];
```

Comment: I agree with @AndreyChernukha.

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution but as @AndreyChernukha said, it can give the wrong value. I don't necessarily need Dictionary, it could be also a 2 dimensions array. I'd just like to know the most adapted and optimized solution.

Comment: @bldcoco : H2CO3 is my SIR, and as he mentioned  `dictionaries are unordered` so if you add a new object (setObject:forKey:) it is not that it will be added at what index, so it becomes difficult to get al converting dict to array and getting in that order. However you can use key as `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key-%d",indexPushed]` then you can search and sort the dictionary.